# Google reCaptcha V3 not working in Incognito browser

Tags: recaptcha-v3, react-google-recaptcha

We are currently facing issues with Google reCaptcha V3 implementation for incognito. It works fine in Standard browser mode.

The issue is when you are filling a form in the incognito mode the Recaptcha score is always lower than 0.5, so the Recaptcha won’t allow submitting the form. If we use the browser in “normal” mode the form will be submitted with no problems at all. We want to know if the incognito mode will represent a bot threat for the ReCaptcha and will give low scores to the user that is filling the form.

Two questions we are trying to address

1. Is this the standard functionality of the reCaptcha for incognito browser mode?
2. Are there other workarounds to solve this problem?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: We're also running into the same issue now after a few weeks with reCaptcha V3.  Incognito scores use to be ok now we're seeing a lot of low scores across browsers and devices even with normal browsing.  Did you ever resolve your issue?

Comment: I too am having this issue any updates?